# Flash Player trust file not working with Embedded browser on linux

Tags: flash, browser, xulrunner, trust

I have an application which embeds a xulrunner based browser. I have to load some flash content in this browser. At certain points of time the flash changes my URL and Page Title to reflect the location in the flash file where I am at. This works fine in a firefox browser when I place my trust file at /etc/FlashPlayerTrust folder with entries for the directory and the swf file I want to trust.( according to the Flash security guide http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/flash_player_admin_guide/flash_player_admin_guide.pdf  the global trust file should be at the same level as the directory which contains the mms.cfg file).

But when I load the flash content from my embedded browser the page title etc don't
 get updated. I have added my applications name also to the flash player trust file. I tried putting my content in a server and accessing it remotely and it works fine from my embedded browser. It is only when the flash content is present locally that URL and page title are not getting updated. This leads to me believe that the problem is with the flash player trust file. The contents of my trust file are as follows:

/home/shivu/activitytest/index.html

/home/shivu/activitytest/gettingstarted.swf

/home/shivu/activitytest/

/home/shivu/app/lv71

Here lv71 is the name of the application which has the embedded browser. 
I tried it with both the Global and User trust files and it doesn't work. Does anybody have any clue what might be going wrong and how I might be able to debug this.

Thanks
jbsp72

Answer (score 1):

For Android systems, the path is:

`/data/data/com.android.browser/app_plugins/com.adobe.flashplayer/.macromedia/Flash_Player/#Security/FlashPlayerTrust/yourfile`

I had to manually create the `"#Security/FlashPlayerTrust"` part of the path.

The name, including the extension, of the file **"yourfile"** is irrelevant.

Here is an example line of its contents:

`/sdcard/html`

Update: Sigh, this trick does not work any more, at least on Android 2.2. with Flash Player 11.1.111.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After much wailing, gnashing of teeth and swearing at Adobe: the solution.

For posterity, the correct location for the trust file is:

```
~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/#Security/FlashPlayerTrust/yourfile.cfg
```

And the format of the entries in this file is:

```
file:////path/to/swf/directory
```

You can of course choose to trust individual .swf files using the above scheme too if you prefer.

Thanks: http://blog.vivoid.com/2009/03/flashplayertrust-not-working-try-adding-a-protocol-prefix/

No Thanks: Adobe.

*Postscript: The Adobe documentation omits the "Flash_Player" directory from the above path. For reference I was using a clean install of Ubuntu 10.10, with flashplugin-nonfree v10.1.102.65ubuntu0.10.10.1 from the repository. The conflicting information to be found on the web may arise from variations within Flash Player packages on different distributions?*