# flash player 11 - can't play local swf files

Tags: flash

in older versions of flash player if I opened a swf file in a web page locally it would bring up a security settings box where I could allow files to play locally - but this doesn't seem to happen in flash player 11 - how do I enable my swfs to play locally?

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers, or just some of them (and if so, which ones)?

Comment: Yep - I tried (on a mac - in FF, Safari, and Chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out (sort of) - I'm not sure why the security box doesn't come up any more, but if you visit the adobe settings manager website:

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html#117118

You can access the different settings panels. In this case I needed the global security settings panel:

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html#117502

From this panel, you can add file / folder locations which you want to allow to run.

Why they put a browser plugin's settings panel inside of a website that is not accessible directly from the plugin's contextual menu is beyond me.

Comment: Your links are the old way to do that thing. Check the link I posted: "Beginning with Flash Player 10.3, the Local Settings Manager supersedes this Online Settings Manager for managing global settings on Windows, Mac, and Linux computers. The Local Settings Manager can be accessed in the Control Panel on Windows and in System Preferences on Mac."

Comment: Just because it is an old way of doing thing doesn't mean it's the wrong way or deserving of a negative vote.

Comment: Maybe you're right for the downvote: anyway, I would have edited my own question, without creating a sort of auto-reply. I upvoted your question.

Answer (score 1):

In OSx (for example) now you can find what you're looking for under System Preferences (Accessories > Flash Player). There's something very similar in Windows. More details here:

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html

Comment: And what if I already added the folder and still I get "A SecurityError occurred: Error #2060". I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, on Android the settings manager does not offer the possibility to specify local file security exceptions. There was a manual workaround mentioned here: [Flash Player trust file not working with Embedded browser on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527425/flash-player-trust-file-not-working-with-embedded-browser-on-linux/8155440#8155440) but even this does not work anymore :-(